# Adding records to existing attribute table but labelled points will not visibly appear?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am a relative newcomer to ArcGIS. I am adding records to an existing attribute table (basically coordinates of towns) but after I save they do not appear on my map desktop. They are entered as points.

Comment: Does your editing feature class have [a category or quantity based symbology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm#GUID-7D77FB92-7FD0-46FD-BEB2-E7B61AA6D865) applied on the map?

Comment: You may wish to see this as well, [_Editing/Selection of features/Disapearing Features_](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/13216).

Answer (score 1):

How are you adding the points?  You need to 'start editing' the point layer, then physically click on the map to add points, then type in the attributes for the new records.  If you're adding points from an XY table, you'll need to 'create feature class from xy table', then append the new feature class to your original feature class.

If you are simply typing coordinates into new records in the attribute table, you're creating records without geometry.

If you've already added a bunch of records without geometry, and have entered the coordinates, you can add geometry to the records using the field calculator.

Comment: Thank you, I will now click on the map to create records. I have been using "start editing" and then saving and "stop editing." Forgive my possible naivete, but if I enter coordinates into the attribute table, is that not where the file pulls from to add the point? I guess that's where the field calculator comes in. Appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  Could you please accept the answer and possibly upvote it if you find it valuable.  The attribute table stores the geometry attribute separately from any coordinate attributes.  To modify the geometry, you have to modify the geometry field, not the coordinate fields.

Comment: Search GIS SE for 'field calculator modify geometry' and you'll find lots of answers if you don't know how to do that.